# Apply operation in sqlalchemy object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model as follows:

```
class Notes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'notes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('articles.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
```

I am saving encoded text in description and want to decode text automatically whenever I call `Notes.description`. Is there any kind of lambda function that I can apply whenever I call `Notes.description`. I know very well that I can perform this operation simply by `decode(Notes.description)` but I can't do this when using `group_concat` to concat multiple notes of an article.

Comment: Given the talk about `group_concat`, this sounds like you'd want a hybrid property.

Comment: I am not sure if `@property` will work inside `group_concat`. I want to `group_concat(Notes.description)`, but simply calling `Notes.description` will give me encoded string .

Comment: I think @IljaEverilä wants to say that there is a decorator named `hybrid_property` comes from `sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid`.

Comment: @YangHG beat me to it, here's the relevant documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html